# How do I associate a listbox VBA Form array associate with absolute address

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, listbox

I am populating a listbox in a form using a range as so:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Names = Range("C6:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)
    For i = LBound(Names, 1) To UBound(Names, 1)
        ListBox1.AddItem Names(i, 1) & "-" & Names(i, 2)
    Next
    OptionButton3.Value = True
End Sub
```

I need to call the address of each of these items later in my code to act upon; in reality each item in the listbox is to select which rows to act upon by the user placing each item in a different listbox as part of the form.

I have tried to redimension the array like so, with no success due to "Constant Expression Required":

```
Dim Names(6 To Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row, Range("C6:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row))
```

What is either the best way to associate the address with the array, or record the list of rows ?

Comment: You are defining `Names` as an array containing the values in those cells. Are you saying you want to associate Names(1,1) with "C6" etc?

Comment: Just add 6 to the `Listindex` of your listbox and you will have the row number.

Comment: I tested the Listindex with `For i = 0 To (ListBox2.ListCount - 1): Debug.Print (Str(ListBox2.ListIndex + 6) + " Test"): Next` but it returns 0 for each item by the time it's in the second box. And yes, I want to associate Names (1,1) with row 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by a rather inelegant hack that I don't particularly like using a helper column listing the row number. There are better ways of doing this I'm sure, but here's what I came up with:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Names = Range("C6:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)
    For i = LBound(Names, 1) To UBound(Names, 1)
        ListBox1.AddItem Names(i, 3) & ": " & Names(i, 1) & "-" & Names(i, 2)
    Next
    OptionButton3.Value = True
End Sub
```

I then recall the row number in my code as follows once the user has selected which items to act on:

```
For i = 0 To (ListBox2.ListCount - 1)
    Dim itemName() As String
    itemName() = Split(ListBox2.list(i), ":")
    deviceRow = itemName(0)
    Debug.Print "Row number: " + deviceRow
    ... <SNIP>
```

It Prints like this:

```
Row number: 10
Row number: 7
Row number: 14
Row number: 9
```

There must be better ways of doing this, but that was my solution.

Comment: Did you try my approach without being forced to split data? - Think I included everything you asked for (of course you could set the `Columnwidths` property of the second column to 0 if you don't want to display more than one column).

Comment: Yeah, I did. By the time the user has selected their items the column number is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

Think this is what you need:

**Code**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
' I. Get started
' a) variables
  Const iOffset As Long = 5                     ' row offset 5, i.e. start at row C6
  Dim names, a                                  ' variant datafield arrays
  Dim i      As Long, n As Long
  Dim ws     As Worksheet
' b) set worksheet object to memory
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")   ' << change to your sheet name
' c) listbox layout just for demo
  Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 2
  Me.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "100;50"
' d) get last row of column C
  n = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
' II. Get values
' a) create 1-based 2-dim variant datafield array
  names = ws.Range("C6:D" & n)
' b) concatenate names and define cell address
  For i = LBound(names, 1) To UBound(names, 1)
    names(i, 1) = names(i, 1) & "-" & names(i, 2)
    names(i, 2) = "C" & i + iOffset
  Next
' III. Fill Listbox
' get values of names array (1-liner, allows more than 10 columns :-)
  ListBox1.List = names
' IV.  Test to get 2nd array column into new array a
  a = Application.Index(names, 0, 2)
  For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
      Debug.Print a(i, 1)
  Next i
' V. clear memory
  Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Note**

I added a constant defining your row Offset (`Const iOffset As Long = 5`) and speeded up code using an array assignment to your `ListBox.List` in **one code statement** instead of adding items one by one (BTW this would allow to use *more than 10 listbox columns*).

As @Rory remarked, just adding your row offset (e.g. +5) to the current active `ListBox1.Listindex` would be sufficient to get the row number. In this case you should only take care that a list row is marked (i.e. to check `If ListBox1.ListIndex > -1 Then` ... do something).